# Post Jqgrid with form elements into the same model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form which has few textboxes to create an account. And a Jqgrid, which displays the created account.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">Save</button>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Account", "AddEditAccount", HttpMethod.Post, new { id = "addeditform", @role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
<div class="panel-body">
//all input field goes here

</div>

<div class="row">
 <table id="grid-json"></table>
    <div id="pager-json"></div>
</div>
}

And my submit click goes here,
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
var gridData = rows edited -- I am able to get this
 $("#addeditform").submit();
});

My controller

public ActionResult AddEditMethod(ViewModel model)
{}
```

In the ViewModel I have the List which i used to bind the data
On page submit, how to get both List and form elements.

Currently with the above code, I am able to get form elements in the controller. I am able to get the edited grid data in jquery before form submit. But how to bind that to model with form elements?

But List is null, as I haven't succeeded in binding the grid data to model. Any help?